# How do I compile a Solidity contract with an import to standalone byte code?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am trying to compile the MetaCoin contract (part of the [Truffle Init Webpack](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-init-webpack/tree/master/contracts)). I need to get the byte code as hex numbers so that I can use it with Nethereum. The MetaCoin contains an import to ConvertLib.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";

contract MetaCoin {
    ...
```

When I compile it (using either Truffle from the command line or the Solidity extension for VS Code), the byte code I get is:

```
0x6060 ... 0073__ConvertLib____________________________6396 ... 0029
```

This is obviously a reference the ConvertLib library. When I use Nethereum to try and deploy the contract:

```
...
var ByteCode = 
    "0x6060 ... 0073__ConvertLib____________________________6396 ... 0029";
var transactionHash = await web3.Eth.DeployContract.SendRequestAsync(
    Abi, ByteCode, Address, Gas, GasPrice);
```

I get the error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Character '_' at index '604' is not valid alphanumeric character.
```

Clearly, it does not like the "ConvertLib" reference in the middle of the byte code. I could just include the library code in the MetaCoin contract and remove the import, but I would like to sort this problem out properly.

How can I compile the MetaCoin contract so that it includes the ConvertLib library in the byte code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
solc --optimize --bin MetaCoin.sol | solc --link --libraries ConvertLib:<address>
```

In order for this to work `ConvertLib` has to be deployed first, the linking will then replace the placeholders like `0073__ConvertLib____________________________6396` with the actual addresses.

To quote the relevant part of the
[documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html):

> If your contracts use libraries, you will notice that the bytecode
>   contains substrings of the form `__LibraryName______`. You can use solc
>   as a linker meaning that it will insert the library addresses for you
>   at those points:
>
> Either add `--libraries "Math:0x12345678901234567890
>   Heap:0xabcdef0123456"` to your command to provide an address for each
>   library or store the string in a file (one library per line) and run
>   `solc` using `--libraries fileName`.
>
> If `solc` is called with the option --link, all input files are
>   interpreted to be unlinked binaries (hex-encoded) in the
>   __LibraryName____-format given above and are linked in-place (if the input is read from stdin, it is written to stdout). All options except
>   --libraries are ignored (including -o) in this case.

Comment: Ah - I see. I didn't realise the ConvertLib & MetaCoin contracts would be deployed to the blockchain separately. Interesting - thanks for that.